# Arduino Exiting Loop To Previous Loop

Tags: c, arduino, robotics, arduino-c++

So currently I am trying to write code for an arduino car/robot to solve a maze made of black tape on white background. The current sensors I am working with is a wheel encoder(lm393), yellow standard motors, and IR emmiters and detectors in paralell(QTR-8RC).

Currently I am having a problem where I have code to follow the line, and I have code to turn the car around 180 degrees by counting the encoder pulses once it exits the line. The problem is that the car just keeps spinning and that is because it is stuck in the function `turnAround();`. Is there any way I can go back to the `lineFollow();` function once my car is done rotating 180 degrees?

The code used is here:

```
void turnAround()
{
// NOW THE problem is that the counter is not jumping back to the line follower
while(countRW <= 27 && countLW <= 27) {
printEncoderMesurements();
analogWrite(RWF, 180);
analogWrite(RWB, 0);
analogWrite(LWF, 0);
analogWrite(LWB, 180);  
}
resetCounters();
followLine();
}
```

```
void followLine() {
if (
((s2 == 0) && (s3 == 1) && (s4 == 1) && (s5 == 0))||
((s2 == 1) && (s3 == 1) && (s4 == 1) && (s5 == 0))||
((s2 == 0) && (s3 == 1) && (s4 == 1) && (s5 == 1))||
((s2 == 0) && (s3 == 0) && (s4 == 1) && (s5 == 1))||
((s2 == 1) && (s3 == 1) && (s4 == 0) && (s5 == 0))||
((s2 == 0) && (s3 == 0) && (s4 == 1) && (s5 == 0))||
((s2 == 0) && (s3 == 1) && (s4 == 0) && (s5 == 0))){
      
    forwards();

}else if(s0 == 1 || s1 == 1) {
slowLeft();
}else if(s7 == 1 || s6 == 1){
slowRight();
}else if((s0 == 0)&&(s1 == 0)&&(s2 == 0) && (s3 == 0) && (s4 == 0) && (s5 == 0) && (s6 == 0) && (s7 == 0)) {
turnAround();

}
}

void loop(){ 
makeIRReadings(); 
printEncoderMesurements(); 
followLine(); 
delay(50); 
}
```

I have tried every variations of different exit(0) or return 0 but none worked.

Comment: don't call followLine inside turnAround. This is recursion and if it goes too many times the program will crash

Comment: I don't see anything ever updating variables in your code.

Comment: Why won't `s0` thru `s7` still be `0`, and another turnaround is called? We don't see the code so maybe that's what `resetCounters()` does too. You should have let the function return to `loop()` as usual, instead of recursing.

Comment: I would start from the propper formating the code.

Comment: You should use an FSM for this. Your loop should look like `void loop() { fsm_step(); }`, and `fsm_step` must depend on the current state and handle step transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is checking if countRW and countLW are less than 28, but while its looping in that while loop, you never update countRW or countLW so they will forever be less than 28.
Also, I'm not sure how your sensors are setup, but it seems like you drive off the line before turning around. So then after it turns around, it's still off the line, so it will call turnAround() again. You need a way to "catch" the line after turning around so it could follow it again.

Comment: Also, just an extra idea: Your if statement is huge, but it seems like at least s3 or s4 will true for it to go forward. You could just use those values for going forward. Or, for example, adding together the sensors on the right and checking if that sum is over a certain value, and same for the left side. Also, since arduinos see 0 as false and 1 as true, just get rid of all the ==n and () around your conditionals. For example, you can use s1 or !s1 depending if you want a 1 or 0 to be true. There are ways to make that statement a lot smaller and more readable.